# Powerpivot: Calculate how many runs it takes to get within 1 standard deviation

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

The data I have is over 90 runs.  Basically, the same test is run 90 times and the data is evaluated for repeat-ability.

Sequentially, over the 90 runs, the cumulative average is calculated. From the first count of the 90 consecutive runs, I'd like to count the runs it takes for the cumulative average to get within 1 sigma of the average within 5 sequential runs.  The first few runs could be greater than 1 sigma, but the cumulative average need to get within 1 sigma before the first 5 consecutive runs are completed.  A cumulative average within the first 5 consecutive runs is considered a pass.  If not then show the total count to reach within 1 sigma.  In any case, determine how many runs it takes to get within 1 sigma.

In Powerpivot, I have as calculated measures the following:

- Average over 90 runs.
- Running Total over 90 runs.
- Cumulative average through 90 runs.
- Standard Deviaton.
- Average plus 1 Standard Deviation.
- Average minus 1 standard deviation.

Need:

Calculate how many runs it takes to get within 1 standard deviation from first run.

```
RunningTotal :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Append1[Value] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( Append1[Run] ), Append1[Run] <= MAX ( Append1[Run] ) )
)


CumulativeAve:=[Running]/[Sum of Run]
```

For Average, Min, Max I showed the same value for each of the runs to plot as references on a pivot chart against the cumulative average:

```
Min:=CALCULATE(MIN(Append1[Value]),FILTER(ALL(Append1[Run]),Append1[Run])) 

Max:=CALCULATE(MAX(Append1[Value]),FILTER(ALL(Append1[Run]),Append1[Run])) 

Average:=CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Append1[Value]),FILTER(ALL(Append1[Run]),Append1[Run]))
```

I then created a measure to show StdDev from which I used to attain Average plus 1 sigma and Average minus 1 sigma:

```
StdDev:=CALCULATE(STDEV.P(Append1[Value]),FILTER(ALL(Append1[Run]),Append1[Run]))     
AvePlusStdev:=[Average]+[StdDev]
AveMinusStdev:=[Average]-[StdDev]
```

Bear with me, I'm still new to DAX and Powerpivot, and new to the Stackoverflow world.

Comment: Great question, now what have you tried so far?

Comment: Many things to no avail.  I'm really a hack at DAX/Powerpivot as far as calculated measures go.  In other words, I'm just a beginner at DAX and Powerpivot learning as I go. The last few weeks realizing the power of Powerpivot and DAX, and trying to harness it for my measured test data.

Comment: Here is running total for each run over 90 runs: Running:=CALCULATE(SUM(Append1[Value]),FILTER(ALL(Append1[Run]),Append1[Run]<=MAX(Append1[Run])))

Comment: Nice, I'd suggest going ahead and adding your last commend (and anything else you've tried so far) to the question. It might incite more people to try and help you out.